# How to fix history.push() not going to next file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-dom, history.js

i am working on a new project in react native, i created a login page, where I placed a to sign-up button, i added function "gotosignUp" to button and wrote function to move to file signup but it doesn't work, any idea why? I am new to react native so begginer misakes are possible :D

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well your project is a react-native project. So you need to use other library like https://reactnavigation.org because history is only for web apps.